# rewrite rules messing up web api 2 /token

Tags: angularjs, oauth, asp.net-web-api2

I'm trying to get an angularjs + web api 2 with OAuth. Basically I select individual accounts from the Visual Studio ASP.NET Web Application template.

I need a rewrite for the angular stuff but I'm finding that makes it so I can't get my /token for the OAuth stuff? How can these 2 play nice?

```
<rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="angularjs routes" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always get this after I post ><

I added this to the conditions and it worked...

```
<add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/token" negate="true" />
```